# How can I get the src of the current loaded script?

Tags: javascript

I load a script from a website:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.mybridge.com/scripts/init.js?IDL=1'></script>
```

Inside this `init.js` script being loaded I have:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var myScript = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
```

but if I try to watch at the `src`:

```
console.log("src is: "+myScript.src);
```

it shows to me a link of another script, not the src of the current (loaded/processed) script.

Where am I wrong? How can I do it?

Comment: There's no reason for the current script to be the last one in the document, is there ?

Comment: What does "currently loaded" mean? Where/when is this code running?

Comment: I mean the `running script` (i.e. the code I wrote above). Is from a source script; how can I get the source src script?

Comment: What do you **really** want ? Know where the script is loaded from ? get the `IDL` ? This looks like a XY question.

Comment: @dystroy: yes, I want to get the IDL value. i.e. the full querystring `var queryString = myScript.src.replace(/^[^\?]+\??/, '');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the URL of the script, you have to know a little more about your scripts, as there's no reason the script you want is the last one in the HTML document.

For example, if you know its name is `"init.js"` and you want the `IDL` parameter, you may do

```
function getIDL(){
     var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
     for (var i=0; i<scripts.length; i++) {
         var m = scripts[i].src.match(/\/init\.js\?IDL=(\d+)/);
         if (m) {
            return m[1]; // return the IDL
         }
     }
     return null;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you boss! Is it alto possible reckon it by name/id? Or just by src?

Comment: @markzzz name of the script element or name of the file ?

Comment: name/id of the script

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
console.log(scripts);
var len = scripts.length;
for(var i = 0 ; i < len ; i++){
    if(scripts[i].src.search('init') >= 0){
       console.log(scripts[i].src) ;
    }
}
```

[JSFIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d6sywLsq/2/)